# CSS diaplay inline-block top aligment

Tags: html, css

I have few divs which I want to display as separate boxes in two columns.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="short-desk">
   <p>BOX 1</p>
</div>

<div class="short-desk">
   <p>BOX 2</p>
</div>
...
```

**CSS:**

```
.short-desk {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 42%;
    height: 180px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

I tried to use css diaplay:inline-block property, but there is some problem with alignment: 
2 boxes in one row are not on same level.

Actually they are working OK with small text inside, but, when I put a little bit longer text, then their level changes and doesn't match each other.

See demo here:

> http://jsfiddle.net/zur4ik/TUGup/1/

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you inadvertently placed the solution in your question title.

Adding this style to your definition seems to give the intended behaviour:

```
.short-desk {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TUGup/3/).

If this isn't what you were looking for, let me know and I'll be happy to help further!

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the spaces between the divs by placing `font-size:0` on the body, and put `overflow:hidden` on the boxes.

http://jsfiddle.net/TUGup/2/

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work. Even on your fiddle two DIVs on second row  don't match top alignment.

Comment: +1 for font-size:0. But i can't fully understand its purpose.

Comment: `font-size:0` isn't needed in this particular case, also it's one of the best solutions for the [spaces between inline-blocks](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) problem.

Comment: Ah yeah, stupid webkit bug. You also need to apply `vertical-align: top` to fix it for webkit.  Otherwise, it works fine in both gecko and trident (firefox and IE)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `overflow:hidden;` to `short-desk` class like this:-

```
.short-desk {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 42%;
    height: 180px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:hidden;           // Add this
}
```

**[FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/TUGup/5/)**

Comment: no, doen't work. Boxes on second row, with long text are still on different vertical level.

Comment: @zur4ik Check the fiddle link.

Comment: Serlite's answer helped. Thanks Vivek for your help.

Comment: It is the specified behavior (last paragragh in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) for `vertical-align`), but looks much like a side effect. I suppose that using `vertical-align` directly is more understandable approach.